# Too many input arguments" error in genetic algorithm

Tags: matlab, genetic-algorithm

I want to minimize a very simple function.

```
function z=f(x)
    f=(x(1)-2)^2+(x(2)-1)^2
end
```

and I write this in matlab command window:

```
>> [x fval]=ga(@f,2)
```

But I get this error:

> ??? Error using ==> ga
>
> Too many input arguments.

Any suggestions to fix this problem?

Comment: What does `which ga` return?

Comment: @DanielR `C:\Users\student\Documents\MATLAB\ga.m`

Comment: This file overwrites the build in. Delete it.

Comment: @DanielR Which file should he delete? You mean `ga.m`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have multiple ga.m, the build in and your own ga.m in `C:\Users\student\Documents\MATLAB\ga.m`, matlab uses

1. Files in the current directory
2. Files in the order they are placed on `path`

Obviously, your `ga.m` is first in order, which causes Matlab to call it instead of the buildin. Either fix the path settings, or delete `C:\Users\student\Documents\MATLAB\ga.m`